# How can I upload and convert file to Google Drive using Android Java?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am uploading a file to google drive successfully, however, am having difficulty setting the convert flag.

Below is what I tried, based on the reference documents I found.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

```
          java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(csvfilepath);
          FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", fileContent);

          // File's metadata.
          File body = new File();
          body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
          body.setMimeType("text/csv");

          File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);//.execute();
          file.setConvert(true);
          file.execute();

          if (file != null) {
            showToast("Data Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
```

https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.Insert.html

Comment: have you read [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui)?

Comment: Yes. I've been over the documentation with a fine toothed comb. In fact most of the code above is from the example google gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set the convert flag to the wrong object, try replacing your code with the following:

```
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(csvfilepath);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", fileContent);

// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
body.setMimeType("text/csv");

// THIS IS THE NEW CODE
Insert request = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
request.setConvert(true);
File file = request.execute();
// END OF NEW CODE

if (file != null) {
  showToast("Data Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: in the insert line what is the service.files() what the service field